# Adding values from Selectors returning NAN instead of number

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-form

I'm getting a NAN return on total. I'm trying to get it to add all available selectors in the following piece of code. See the total line...

```
Form = connect(state => {
  const equipmentTotal = selector(state, 'equipment.total'); 
  const softwareTotal = selector(state, 'softwares.total');
  const thirdPartyEquipmentTotal = selector(state, 'thirdPartys.totalFees');
  const miscTotal = selector(state, 'miscTotal');
  const tradeInTotal = selector(state, 'orderHeader.tradein');

  return { //Returning data like the following is the equivalent of using ({ }) which is an object-literal as an expression in ES6... docs for more info.
    total: equipmentTotal + softwareTotal + thirdPartyEquipmentTotal + miscTotal + tradeInTotal,
  };
  },
)(Form);
```

But if a single one of the selectors is undefined (null) it returns NAN. Is there a way I can set the Selector to return zero if no number is defined in state? Ideally, I don't want to set a default value of 0 within the form field as it would require the user to highlight and delete it, or potentially accidentally add a 0 to the end of an entered number. So user types 29 after selecting field yeilding 290 accidentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `||`(or) JavaScript operator. It returns the first truthy value. So if the value returned from your selector is `undefinded`, `null`, or even `0`, it will return `0`;

```
Form = connect(state => {
    const equipmentTotal = selector(state, 'equipment.total') || 0;
    const softwareTotal = selector(state, 'softwares.total') || 0;
    const thirdPartyEquipmentTotal = selector(state, 'thirdPartys.totalFees') || 0;
    const miscTotal = selector(state, 'miscTotal') || 0;
    const tradeInTotal = selector(state, 'orderHeader.tradein') || 0;

    return { //Returning data like the following is the equivalent of using ({ }) which is an object-literal as an expression in ES6... docs for more info.
        total: equipmentTotal + softwareTotal + thirdPartyEquipmentTotal + miscTotal + tradeInTotal,
    };
},
)(Form);
```

Comment: This works but yields 22 + 22 = 022022... It still appears to be a string related issue. The redux-form fields are both set to type="number", but in the Redux state they appear as "22". Should I add a normalizer with something like Number(val)? I'm very confused by this...

Comment: Hmm, yeah I'm also confused. You should make sure that the values being stored in your reducer are being stored as numbers and not strings. You might want to try `parseInt` on them before saving them to your reducer state.

Comment: You can also do: `total: parseInt(equipmentTotal,10) + parseInt(softwareTotal,10) + parseInt(thirdPartyEquipmentTotal,10)...`, but that's just putting a band-aid on the real issue.